# What is the python-poetry config file after 1.2.0 release?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have been using [python-poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) for over a year now. 
After [poetry 1.2.0](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/releases/tag/1.2.0) release, I get such an info warning:

```
Configuration file exists at ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry,
reusing this directory.

Consider moving configuration to ~/Library/Preferences/pypoetry,
as support for the legacy directory will be removed in an upcoming release.
```

But in docs, it is still indicated for macOS: `~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry` 
https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/

My question is that if `~/Library/Preferences/pypoetry` is the latest decision what should I do for moving configuration to there? 
Is just copy-pasting enough?

[image: poetry-config-file-for-macos]

Comment: https://github.com/platformdirs/platformdirs/issues/47

Comment: Yes @MarekR you are right. Also it is mentioned in [locations.py](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/1e1585321e90a771af3da33f5154278fe9ee5ca2/src/poetry/locations.py#L24). Thank you very much.

Comment: This has changed again! I'm running poetry 1.7.1, and it says `Consider moving TOML configuration files to ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry, as support for the legacy directory will be removed in an upcoming release.` Therefore, if you're getting the message SADIK reports, just upgrade poetry.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like it is as simple as copy/pasting to the new directory.

I got the same error after upgrading to Poetry 1.2.  So I created a `pypoetry` folder in the new `Preferences` directory, copy/pasted the `config.toml` to it, and just to be safe, I renamed the original folder to:

`~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry_bak`

After doing this and running `poetry -V`, the error is gone.

Comment: I had the same issue and now it works properly, thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

The copy paste equivalent of Ryan's answer:

```
cp -R ~/Library/Application\ Support/pypoetry ~/Library/Preferences/
mv ~/Library/Application\ Support/pypoetry ~/Library/Application\ Support/pypoetry_bak
poetry -V
```

(Couldn't comment with code block formatting)

Comment: This sadly doesn't work for me, still get the error

Answer (score 2):

Only the `config.toml` file need to move to `~/LibraryPreferences/pypoetry`, meanwhile modify the `~/Library/Application\ Support/pypoetry/config.toml` file name as `config.toml_bak`.

Answer (score 1):

```
mv /Users/$USER/Library/Preferences/pypoetry/config.toml /Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/pypoetry
```

Comment: This breaks when `~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry` does not yet exist.